# Why am i having a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays, class, for-loop

So the method is to see if a book exists in the library:

```
public boolean exists(Book l) {                      
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (books[i].equals(l)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Library.exists(Library.java:13)
```

What am i doing wrong here?

So i got the answer thanks to you guys :) So the problem was that i did not add books inside the library! The method to add books:

```
public void addBook(Book l) {
    if (l == null) {
        System.out.println("Book is unini..!");
        return;
    }

    if (exists(l)) {
        System.out.println("Book exists!");
        return;
    }

    if (books.length == index) {
        Book[] temp = new Book[books.length + 3];
        for(int i=0;i<books.length;i++){
            temp[i]=books[i];
        }
        books=temp;
    }
    books[index++] = l;

}
```

Comment: Your array contains null elements because you didn't add anything to it?

Comment: One of your books in the array is null.

Comment: or even `books` itself is null.

Comment: Where did you define `index`?

Comment: Your books are `null`. Did you initialize them ? Apart from `books = new Book[x]` did you assign values to them ?

Comment: I corrected it :)  So the problem was that i did not add any books in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities. books is null or books[i] is null.
If there was an error in equals or if l is null you would see it in the StackTrace too.

Comment: two only. `l` can be null because it's not dereferenced (there is no `l.something()`)